# Why are windows shortcut not accessible when reading the directory

Tags: java, c#, node.js, windows, shortcut-file

Recently I tried to write a small application to help me sort the shortcut on my desktop.

I quickly noticed that the shortcuts (.lnk, .url) created by the system or an application ( an installer, the steam "create shortcut" function, etc) did not appear in the list of processed files.

Thinking that the problem came from Java, I also made the test in C#, Dart and NodeJS and each time the same result: the shortcuts created with the function "Create a shortcut" of the right click menu are well seen and processed by my program, the shortcuts created by the system are ignored and absent from the listings.

Do the shortcuts created by the system have a different "marking" from an authorization point of view? Is there a way to be able to process them?

I attach my NodeJS test code, if needed I could share the other code. 
I also specify that all my tests were carried out with Windows 10 Pro 1909 (18363.657) on an Administrator account.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');

var desktopPath = fs.readdirSync(`${os.homedir()}${path.sep}Desktop`);

for(var i = 0; i < desktopPath.length; i++) {
    console.log(desktopPath[i]);
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Nice find, indeed they seem to be in the Public/Desktop folder and not just in the ${user}/Desktop folder. I'll go to bed less silly tonight, thank you @the_lotus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desktop that you see is a combination of multiple desktop folders.

```
C:\Users\{username}\Desktop
C:\Users\Public\Desktop
…
```

Do a right-click properties to see where the link is stored.

Comment: Note that the user's desktop is not necessarily in its default location in the user profile directory "C:\Users\{username}", so `${os.homedir()}${path.sep}Desktop` is wrong. A program must query the shell for the location, such as via the shell C API function `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will look into that .

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the exact same problem in Java.  I was able to get around it by creating a symbolic link instead of a shortcut.  To create a symbolic link similar to *NIX, you need to use the mklink command.  I also had to run the command prompt as an administrator in order to get sufficient privileges.

```
mklink myLocalFile \\host\Users\userId\Documents\...\myNetworkFile
```